# How to make a shape which is made using css borders responsive?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a shape by using css borders

```
<div class="shape>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the above code:

```
.shape{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

I would like to make this shape responsive. Is it possible? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use % on width and height.

Comment: add % to width.

Comment: @Troyer 0% of width is still 0, and borders can't be in %

Comment: then change your `px` to `vw` instead.

Comment: If i am looking to create a basic shape, i would First look search icon font or svg. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use viewport units:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

```css
.shape{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5vw solid transparent;
border-right: 5vw solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10vw solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS units `vh` and `vw` you can define your lengths relative (as percentage) to the viewport height and width.

```
border-width: 10vw;
```

With CSS percentages, you can define your lengths relative to the nearest ancestor element having `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`.

```
border-width: 10%;
```

With CSS media queries, you can define steps in which your content is rendered in different ways depending on the viewport size.

```
.shape {
    border-width: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .shape {
        border-width: 50px;
    }
}
```

These are all basic CSS skills. You can read about these for example on MDN:

- [Length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)
- [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the clear explanation and references :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
.shape{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5vw solid transparent;
border-right: 5vw solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10vw solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="shape">ABC
</div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootstrap for the same. It is very easy to make any thing responsive using Bootstrap .Or you can try by setting the margins to auto.